# Doctrine get result issue

Tags: mysql, symfony, dql

I got DQL like this:

```
$sql =$qb->select('c')
->from('Cusomter','c')
->where('c.login = :login')
->setParameter('login',$login);
$rs = $sql->getQuery()->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_OBJECT);
```

But I got the following error

> Fatal error: Class 'customer\Query' not found in
>   MyNameSpace\customer.php

Do i need to use any namespace?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to actually tell `getResult` to hydrate_object, its default behaviour, and therefore called from the method itself.

try:

```
$rs = $sql->getQuery()->getResult();
```

if you want to know the right namespace for the constant though its:

```
Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT
```

Comment: but when i select  `username,id` only then it would return object but not array. Is there anyway i could do it?

Comment: youve asked for an object.. use Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY instead

Comment: Sorry. what i meant it is when i query for `login,id`, then it would return the result as array but not object. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;
```

or

```
\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY
```